# Why result of rest api mapping is null?

Tags: flutter, api, rest, model-view-controller

Here is my controller code, why is data returning as a null value?

```
Future<List<GetEntityKindsModel>> getEntityKinds() async
{
  List<GetEntityKindsModel> data = [];
 try
     {
      dynamic response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      dynamic jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data = jsonData.map((item)=>GetEntityKindsModel.fromJson(item));
      print('Data -- $data');
     }
     catch(e)
  {
    print('Error -- $e');
  }
  return data;
}
```

I tried typecasting both jsonData and data into list format but still data returned as null. Is there any issue my with mapping of model to controller? Model has 2 nested classes

```
    class GetEntityKindsModel {
  GetEntityKindsModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.type,
    required this.classType,
    required this.label,
    required this.pluralLabel,
    this.sharedVisibility,
    this.subscribe,
    required this.id,
    this.entityName,
    required this.parentEntityId,
    required this.languageId,
    this.timestamp,
    this.tagText,
    required this.entityIndex,
    this.code,
    this.blobKey,
  });

  String name;
  Type type;
  ClassType classType;
  String label;
  String pluralLabel;
  String? sharedVisibility;
  Subscribe? subscribe;
  int id;
  String? entityName;
  int parentEntityId;
  LanguageId languageId;
  int? timestamp;
  String? tagText;
  List<String> entityIndex;
  Code? code;
  BlobKey? blobKey;

  factory GetEntityKindsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetEntityKindsModel(
    name: json["name"],
    type: typeValues.map[json["type"]]!,
    classType: classTypeValues.map[json["classType"]]!,
    label: json["label"],
    pluralLabel: json["pluralLabel"],
    sharedVisibility: json["sharedVisibility"],
    subscribe: subscribeValues.map[json["subscribe"]]!,
    id: json["id"],
    entityName: json["entityName"],
    parentEntityId: json["parentEntityId"],
    languageId: languageIdValues.map[json["languageId"]]!,
    timestamp: json["timestamp"],
    tagText: json["tagText"],
    entityIndex: List<String>.from(json["entityIndex"].map((x) => x)),
    code: json["code"] == null ? null : Code.fromJson(json["code"]),
    blobKey: json["blobKey"] == null ? null : BlobKey.fromJson(json["blobKey"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "type": typeValues.reverse[type],
    "classType": classTypeValues.reverse[classType],
    "label": label,
    "pluralLabel": pluralLabel,
    "sharedVisibility": sharedVisibility,
    "subscribe": subscribeValues.reverse[subscribe],
    "id": id,
    "entityName": entityName,
    "parentEntityId": parentEntityId,
    "languageId": languageIdValues.reverse[languageId],
    "timestamp": timestamp,
    "tagText": tagText,
    "entityIndex": List<dynamic>.from(entityIndex.map((x) => x)),
    "code": code?.toJson(),
    "blobKey": blobKey?.toJson(),
  };
}

class BlobKey {
  BlobKey({
    required this.blobKey,
  });

  String blobKey;

  factory BlobKey.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BlobKey(
    blobKey: json["blobKey"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "blobKey": blobKey,
  };
}

enum ClassType { STATIC, NULL, DYNAMIC }

final classTypeValues = EnumValues({
  "dynamic": ClassType.DYNAMIC,
  "null": ClassType.NULL,
  "static": ClassType.STATIC
});

class Code {
  Code({
    required this.value,
  });

  String value;

  factory Code.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Code(
    value: json["value"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "value": value,
  };
}

enum LanguageId { EN_US }

final languageIdValues = EnumValues({
  "en_US": LanguageId.EN_US
});

enum Subscribe { YES, EMPTY }

final subscribeValues = EnumValues({
  "": Subscribe.EMPTY,
  "yes": Subscribe.YES
});

enum Type { PRIMARY, RELATED }

final typeValues = EnumValues({
  "PRIMARY": Type.PRIMARY,
  "RELATED": Type.RELATED
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of print statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdX04.png)

Model class has been made from app.quicktype.io based on the json response of the api, which is too long so can't post here.

Comment: Can you put a debug breakpoint on your fromJson method in `GetEntityKindsModel`? You'll find which value is set to null.

Comment: What do the prints say? Also, it seems impossible to me that your function returns `null`. It should at the very least return an empty list

Comment: @Ivo the print statements return json object lists in the form [{}]

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Either it comes in the "Error" part and prints that error, or it comes in the "Data" part for which I expect something like `[Instance of 'GetEntityKindsModel', ... , Instance of 'GetEntityKindsModel']` or an empy list. It would be helpful if you included the exact print in your question and also the response.body, or at least a part of it if it's too big

Comment: @Ivo ok I am updating the question with screenshots of the response.body and the 'data' variable printed

Comment: @Demir I tried to put debug breakpoint then but I could not understand. Though now I understood. Thanks a lot anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is

```
Error -- Null check operator used on a null value
```

It would have been useful if you mentioned that before..

It simply means that you are using `!` on variable that is `null`. In your code there is 4 places where this can happen:

```
type: typeValues.map[json["type"]]!,

classType: classTypeValues.map[json["classType"]]!,

subscribe: subscribeValues.map[json["subscribe"]]!,

languageId: languageIdValues.map[json["languageId"]]!,
```

I'd suggest to remove the `!` for all 4 and make the corresponding field nullable, like

```
  Type? type;
  ClassType? classType;
  Subscribe? subscribe;
  LanguageId? languageId;
```

Subscribe is already like this.

Comment: thank you for your response but it didn't resolve the issue. Could there be an issue because of the 2 nested classes in my model?

Comment: thank you so much!! Code is working absolutely fine now. God bless you, thanks a ton!!